# Getting two model properties into one column in gridview, ASP.NET MVC 5.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I have two model properties, DateFrom and DateTo of type DateTime. I'd like, in my gridview to merge these properties into one column, how can this be achieved? For now, every property appears as its own column.

The thing I want is, in some way, to display in one column a date from, and a date to, DateFrom is 2017-10-11 and DateTo is 2017-10-12, e.g.

```
Date of the report
2017-10-11
2017-10-12
```

Comment: Use a view model with a property that combines and formats the 2 values

Answer (score -1):

supposed your model is like this

```
public class TableModel 
{
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }    
    public string StringDate { get; set; }
}
```

then create a method that will concat the DateFrom and DateTo

```
public static Concatenator()
{
    StringDate = string.Format("Date From: {0} to {1}", DateFrom, DateTo);
}
```

then instead of using DateFrom and DateTo to the grid view, use the StringDate

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Biometric ID</th>
        <th>Date In and Out</th>        
    </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody data-bind="foreach: tblTemp_biometric_logss">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: BiometricID "> </td>
            <td data-bind="text: StringDate"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. I've tried it in a modified way, without the method:

model.StringDate = string.Format("Date From: {0} to {1}",   model.DateFrom, model.DateTo); and I get it on one line: Date From: 2017-10-12 06:00:00 to 2017-10-12 06:00:00

This I can get to work myself, but I want each date on its own line. First the older date (date from), until the later date (date to) on each line. As the example above. I have though, not tried your index.cshml code, but I dunno that will show something else?

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned they are using knockout

Comment: the point is instead of using the dateto and datefrom to the gridview, juts use the concatenated one

Comment: @sir Kryman, what do you mean 'each line'? like string.Format("From {0} n\  {1}", DateFrom, DateTo);?